# Understanding a regex expression

Tags: java, regex

This expression evaluates a string to see if every character is a digit.  I don't understand the `-?`.  I know that `?` means once or no times, but I'm not sure what putting dash in front of it means.

```
-?\d+
```

Answer (score 7):

This is needed  because an integer may be negative in which case it will start with a minus (`-`). So what you do here is to check for sequence of 1 or more digits optionally preceded by a single minus.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Still learning how to use regex I guess.

Answer (score 6):

It is not a special character. The dash is there to allow negative numbers.